# ApexChart donut

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy tratando de obtener gráfico de ApexChart donut, desde una tabla de MySQL como se muestra continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consulta que uso:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, COUNT(IF(status = 0, 1, NULL)) as resueltas, COUNT(*) - COUNT(IF(status = 0, 1, NULL)) as pendientes, COUNT(IF(status = 2, 1, NULL)) as reabietas FROM incidences
```

Y me muestra este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera mostrar el resultado de la tabla en un grafico apexchart donut, este es el ejemplo base: https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-donut/

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento, pero aun no se como usarlo con exactitud

Esta consulta es la que tengo en mi controlador

```
$incidences_circule = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) as total, COUNT(IF(status = 0, 1, NULL)) as resueltas, COUNT(*) - COUNT(IF(status = 0, 1, NULL)) as pendientes, COUNT(IF(status = 2, 1, NULL)) as reabietas FROM incidences WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())');
```

```js
<script>
  var options = {
          series: [<?php foreach($incidences_circule as $reg){echo ''.$reg->total',';} ?>],
          chart: {
          type: 'donut',
        },
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 200
            },
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom'
            }
          }
        }]
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#circle-chart"), options);
        chart.render();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

tienes un problema al generar tu array, si lo haces con la función actual, te generara comas de mas y podría darte errores de sintaxis. puedes usar la siguiente forma, utilizando solo la función json_encode() pasándole como parámetro tu array, utilizando array_values() para obtener un array de los valores de los atributos de tu array y array_keys() para obtener un array solo con el nombre de los atributos y asi poder alimentar al script como te lo solicita

```js
var options = {

series: [10,20,20,25,25], //eliminar esto
//series: <?php echo json_encode(array_values($incidences_circule)); ?>,


labels: ["aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"], //eliminar esto
//labels: <?php echo json_encode(array_keys($incidences_circule)); ?>,

chart: {
    type: 'donut',
},
responsive: [{
    reakpoint: 480,
    options: {
       chart: {
           width: 200
       },
       legend: {
           position: 'bottom'
      }
    }
   }]
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#circle-chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="circle-chart" >
 
</div>
```

Comment: Aun sigo teniendo problemas, no me muestra la gráfica.

Comment: ¿que te imprime $incidences_circule ? y ¿tienes el elemento con la id circle-chart?, ¿que error te arroja la consola?

Comment: mejore el ejemplo de la respuesta que puse

Comment: usando el ejemplo de la web oficial si logro cargar los datos de prueba, pero cuando uso mi consulta $incidences_circule hace conflicto con apexchart

Comment: Puedes imprimir tu arreglo para ver qué arroja?

Comment: Esto es lo que me muestra el resultado, de hacer la consulta: array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1395 ▼
    +"total": 170
    +"resueltas": 104
    +"pendientes": 66
    +"reabietas": 28
  }
]

Comment: listo, corregi la respuesta, ahora te deberia funcionar, el problema es que debes entregar un arreglo que solo contenga los valores, y otro arreglo que solo contenga los nombres de los atributos

Comment: Cuando ejecuto mi consultado obtengo este resultado: series: [{"total":170,"resueltas":104,"pendientes":66,"reabietas":28}],
       labels: [0],

Comment: usaste array_keys() y array_values() ?

Comment: Si use el codigo que me diste: series: <?php echo json_encode(array_values($incidences_circule)); ?>, <?php echo json_encode(array_keys($incidences_circule)); ?>, y el resultado obtenido fue: [{"total":170,"resueltas":104,"pendientes":66,"reabietas":28}], labels: [0],